# Django template renders {% trans %} strings in strange order

Tags: html, django

I'm working on supporting Arabic in a Django web database, and I'm encountering some very strange rendering behavior. Specifically I'm trying to reorder the words on the page from right to left, all of them being individually gathered strings in the template (either from a context variable or a trans tag). Hopefully these images will illustrate the problem clearly.

English is the project default.
Django version is 1.6.

In English, everything is fine
[image]
yields[image]

However in Arabic, the same markup results in this, with the cultural period block rendered at the end.
[image]

But if I take that first trans tag out and replace it with a string like this
[image]
the order is correct
[image]

Now here's where it gets very strange. If I add some characters after the first trans tag (cp in this case), it renders correctly
[image]
yields
[image]

But if I add a character *before* the trans tag (a colon in this case), it gets split up in a very bizarre way
[image]
yields[image]

I'm really hoping that there are some underlying rules that Django uses while translating that can explain this. I'm really hoping that it's not (as I'm theorizing) caused by a tiny lag in the time that translation takes causing some parts of the template to render before others...

I should also mention that a number of context variables are passed to the template, and there are looping structures and if statements outside of the markup shown in the screenshots.

UPDATE: With a little more testing I believe I'm finding that if more than one trans strings are next to each other, they will be rendered right to left, even if they appear left to right in the template. If a non-trans character is introduced it "resets" this pattern and everything before/after it is rendered as a set of right to left text. Unfortunately, `&nbsp;` doesn't work to separate these strings, nor does putting them in different divs. I may need to use `<br>` but style-wise I'd rather not...

Comment: It don't think it's a django related issue, you should solve it with css/html.

Comment: It's probably related to Arabic being shown right-to-left.

Comment: But what is causing Arabic to render right to left? Django, or the browser?